# Javascript/PHP: send a pop up or some alert to users who have permissions?

Tags: javascript, php, popup

I have a site that is used by operators in the factory that don't log in so have zero permissions, as well as users in the office who have permissions.

What I need to do is, upon the click of a button that submits a note to the SQL database for a certain job and operation number, send a pop up or some kind of alert message to those that are logged in.

This could be in the form of simply opening a new tab or any method really.

What I've got so far is a cell that highlights the relevant job that has a note, but I want to provide an alert for when a new message is present, as opposed to the just old note displaying the highlighted cell.

Can anybody please provide some suggestions?

EDIT:
Sorry, here's the code on the operator's page, that requires no permissions to update the database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveNotes() {
        var jobID = "<?php echo $_GET['jobID']; ?>";
        var operation = "<?php echo $_GET['operation']; ?>";
        var nnotes = document.getElementById('notes').value;
        if (nnotes == 'null') nnotes = "";
        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+operations+SET+notes='"+nnotes+"'+WHERE+jobID="+jobID+"+AND+operation="+operation); 
        alert("Your note has been submitted")
    }
    </script>
<body>
<input method="post" onLoad="initialise();" class="onload auto notes" data-type="text" style="display:inline;" id="notes" value="<?php echo $row["notes"]; ?>" size="15" placeholder="Type a note..">
        <button onClick="saveNotes();" style="font-size:25px;padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;" alert="Your note has been sent" >SEND</button></td>
```

What I want is for an alert of some kind to pop up on a page titled 'home.html' for users with permission>1

I hope that helps..

Comment: Can you give reference of your site link? Or any portion of code will be better to see instead of talking in general..!

Comment: window.alert("message"); will open a popup with the specified message. Is that what you're looking for? If you're having more specific problems with displaying alerts, it would help to include the details. Otherwise, if you're just looking for an introduction to popups in the browser, google might be a better option :)

Comment: Sorry, updated now..

Comment: On a side note, the receiving end of this `"editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+operations+SET+notes='"+nnotes+"'+WHERE+jobID="+jobID+"+AND+operation="+operation` is very likely not going to be a good idea.  This looks like an sql injection issue.

Comment: Also, these may be an XSS issue: `var jobID = "<?php echo $_GET['jobID']; ?>";` and `var operation = "<?php echo $_GET['operation']; ?>";`